# Remove a list item in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'Div 4 A Herrar': {'0': {'awayScore': '0',
                          'awayTeam': 'Floda BoIF',
                          'events': [],
                          'homeScore': '0',
                          'homeTeam': 'SKIF Semberijaaaah',
                          'tempTime': '10:00',
                          'time': 'FT'},
                    '1': {'awayScore': '0',
                          'awayTeam': 'Kode IF',
                          'events': [{'eventID': '3215',
                                      'eventScore': '1-0',
                                      'eventTime': 'HT',
                                      'eventType': 'Goal-timocin',
                                      'name': 'timocin',
                                      'selectedTeam': 'homeTeam'},
                                     {'eventID': '2312',
                                      'eventScore': '2-0',
                                      'eventTime': 'HT',
                                      'eventType': 'Goal-timocin',
                                      'name': 'timocin',
                                      'selectedTeam': 'homeTeam'}],
                          'homeScore': '2',
                          'homeTeam': 'Partille IF FK',
                          'tempTime': '11:00',
                          'time': 'FT'},
                    '2': {'awayScore': '0',
                          'awayTeam': 'Romelanda UF',
                          'events': [],
                          'homeScore': '0',
                          'homeTeam': 'IK Kongah\\u00e4lla',
                          'tempTime': '12:00',
                          'time': 'FT'}}}
```

What i want to be able to do is to remove a specific event in the **events** list. What i know beforehand is the first two keys meaning:

```
"Div 4 A Herrar" and the integer number that represents a dictionary item
```

I also have the the **eventID** for the event that i need to remove.

So for example to make it more clear for you, lets say that i wanted to remove an event with the eventID 3215. I would then have this information to be able to delete:

```
"Div 4 A Herrar", 1, 3215'
```

If something is unclear please do ask and i will update my question to be more specific.

**EDIT1**

This is what i could only think of doing:

```
for event in dict["Div 4 A Herrar"][1]["events"]:
    if(event["eventID"] == "3215"):
        # this is where i got stuck since i had no idea how to proceed from here.
```

Comment: Your dictionary sample is full of errors; it cannot be pasted back into a Python session.

Comment: Why would you say it is full of errors when it is clearly working for me? What i did was cut out a this portion of my bigger dictionary to make it more readable so the only thing i might have forgot was to remove some brackets at the end ? @MartijnPieters

Comment: Dont be so hungry to vote down guys. It is a well formulated question i dont see what the problem is

Comment: @TimoCengiz: `"eventID = 3215` is not a valid dictionary key-value pair, and has an unterminated quote. There are more such errors. There isn't even a surrounding dictionary, you gave us a key-value pair from a larger dictionary.

Comment: @Meruem: I don't see an attempt to solve this yet though. Nor is there expected output, or an error message if there was a full attempt.

Comment: I updated the question, i wrote those manually since i had some problems when copy pasting, thank you @MartijnPieters

Comment: I updated it. Since thats the only thing i could come up with i did not see any reason to post it. Other than that i did some research and read in a few places that you cant remove while iterating so you should use list comprehensions but that was really confusing so i turned here.. @MartijnPieters

Comment: Notice that the keys in your second level dictionary are not integers, but strings? So, perhaps `dict["Div 4 A Herrar"]["1"]["events"]` will get you a bit closer to what you want... I suspect `dict["Div 4 A Herrar"][1]["events"]` (with an integer as the second level index) throws a `KeyError`, as `dict["Div 4 A Herrar"][1]` will not return a dictionary that can further be indexed with `...["events"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def remove_event(dicts, key, id, event_id):
    if key in dicts and id in dicts[key] and "events" in dicts[key][id]:
        dicts[key][id]['events'] = [event for event in dicts[key][id]['events']
                                    if event["eventID"] != event_id]
    else:
        raise ValueError("The actual Events could not be found")

remove_event(data, "Div 4 A Herrar", "1", "3215")
```

Just filter the event from the `events` list, with a list comprehension, like shown in the function above. The key here is,

```
[event for event in dicts[key][id]["events"] if event["eventID"] != event_id]
```

It creates a new list, by iterating the `dicts[key][id]["events"]` and it includes the current `event` dictionary only if the `event`'s `eventID` is not the same as the one you pass to the function.

Comment: Do you know if this one is faster or the answer provided by taesu

Comment: @TimoCengiz Creating a list with LC happens in C code internally. So, my bet would be on this code only.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_event(d,d_id,key,event_id):
    # d = dictionary 
    # d_id = 'Div 4 A Herrar'
    # key = '1'
    # event_id = '3215'

    # create temp list
    lst = []
    # loop the events list
    for event in d[d_id][key]['events']:
        # if event_id does not match
        if event['eventID'] != event_id:
            # append to temp list
            lst.append(event)
    # make that temp list the events list
    d[d_id][key]['events'] = lst
```

Comment: I think that you need to define the lst before the for loop since there could be more than 1 event meaning the lst will be empty each time it loops @taesu

Comment: I like this code and it works but i will put the correct answer to the one that is the fastest. Thank you for your time